# Azure Resource Manager (ARM) Template parameter undefined

Tags: azure, azure-resource-manager, azure-rm-template

I have created an ARM template user-defined function with a parameter. But it is getting an error "The parameter 'testParam' is undefined". This is my user-defined function content.

```
"functions": [
{
  "namespace": "testns",
  "members": {
    "keyVaultAccessPolicyFunc": {
      "parameters": [
        {
          "name": "testParam",
          "type": "string"
        }
      ],
      "output": {
        "type": "array",
        "value": [
          {
            "objectId": "[reference(concat('Microsoft.Web/Sites',parameters('testParam'))).identity.principalId]",
            "permissions": {
              "keys": [
                "all"
              ],
              "secrets": [
                "all"
              ]
            },
            "tenantId": "[reference(concat('Microsoft.Web/Sites',parameters('testParam'))).identity.tenantId]"
          }
        ]
      }
    }
  }
}
]
```

I referred this documentation https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-resource-manager/resource-group-authoring-templates#functions to create this user-defined function in ARM template.

Comment: how are you calling it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't use the reference() function (or any run-time function) in a UDF.